# Extending XML Comments Snippet in ASP.NET(VB/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, xml-comments

I am trying to expand the default XML Comments snippet. After doing some research, I found out what the file name where this xml is generated from-- VBXMLDoc.xml. But, I am not able to find it on my system. I am using VSTS 2012. For 2010, looks like it will be in C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

But, I cannot find it. Please let me know in 2012, how can I extend the Auto generted XML Comments snippet (''' is the shortcut key)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it first and save it in the same folder as for vs2010 I think. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2010/05/25/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor.aspx

Comment: I've read the article before posting. I copied to C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0. No luck. Thanks for reply

Comment: You could try C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0 too.